# The Following simple query does not complete. Prepared Statement

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, prepared-statement

i have the following query:

```
String updatequery = "UPDATE tbl_page SET linkCount = ?, pageProcessed = 1 WHERE pageUrl =?";
PreparedStatement updatestmt = kon.prepareStatement(updatequery);
updatestmt.clearParameters();
//updatestmt.setQueryTimeout(10);
updatestmt.setInt(1, linkCount);
updatestmt.setString(2, urlLink);
updatestmt.executeUpdate();
```

When i set the query timeout for 10 seconds it will catch an exception the query timed out. but when i dont it goes on waiting. Whats wrong with the query? `pageUrl` column is the Primary Key with `varchar(900)`

I know something might be wrong with the prepared statement because when i run this query in MS SQl Server Management Studio ('?' replaced with its value) it works fine.

Am i  missing something in Java or MSSQL?

Comment: Do you have other queries that functioning properly via JDBC?

Comment: yes only this one is problematic.

Comment: Performance-wise, VARCHAR columns over 4 are less than ideal.  This is one of the cases where I'd suggest using an INT `ID` column as the primary key, and use a UNIQUE constraint on the URL column

Comment: @OMGPonies yes i'll change that.(Running tests for now) but the main problem is unsolved.

Answer (score 2):

Since the code looks just fine, this could be an issue at database side. May be someone else has blocked the row by updating it and not doing a commit/rollback (most possibly from you MS-SQL Server Management studio !). You could look for locks owned by other processes for the same record so that you can be sure that this is not a database issue.

Answer (score 1):

Create an index on pageUrl:

```
create index tbl_page_pageUrl_index on tbl_page(pageUrl);
```

That will allow speedy access to the rows you want to update.

Without this index, the database must do a full table scan, and when combined with an `update` command, if likely to lead to lock contention and possibly even deadlocks, depending on your locking options.

Comment: I think it's already the PK, guessing that he mistyped `urlLink`  instead.

Comment: sorry for the mistake. `pageUrl` is the PK in tbl_page